# How to handle a remote database connection failure

Tags: java, mysql

I plan to have a game server and remotely host a database that will store everything about a player from the game server. My question is, what would be the best thing to do if the game server loses connection to the remote database and is unable to save a player at that given moment.

My only idea is to have a local database and a secondary database connection on the game server, and save the player locally. Once the connection came back I would somehow synchronize the remote database with the local one. (Not sure on how to do this efficiently either)

Comment: The answer will depend on how critical the information is. If it's just "cloud storage" for when the user moves between devices, then having a localised cache which synced with the server is a viable solution. If the information is time sensitive, then you need to be prepared to "block" or "disconnect" the user in some meaningful way

Comment: @MadProgrammer The game server would attempt to save the player when they logout, I plan to add a flag to the players account when they login stating they're logged in. I'm just not sure if I should maybe keep trying to reconnect in the game server and queue up queries to run for when the connection come back.

Comment: What happens if they "drop out" while they are in a disconnected state? As to your question - that would depend on how important the data is to the player been able to play the game.  If you're just storing scores/stats, then having a local database is a good solution, which is then synced over time back to the server. If it's something more critical, then you will need to consider placing the player in a "disconnected" state and limiting what they can do until you have a connection again. In either case, some kind of local cache isn't a bad idea

Comment: I thought that would probably be the best idea as well. Would you have any suggestions on how to go about updating the remote database with the local one once the connection is regained?

Comment: Data synchronization is not a small topic and how/what will depend a lot on what data you have.  Part of the problem is going to be determining the time data was created, so you update the data in the right direction

Comment: A simple timestamp in the table called "updated_at" would work for that I think.